# Anyone know why is my vscode color picker showing preview of the same colour twice?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

Im using vscode version 1.67.2
c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5
x64
[the image of color picker showed twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRGRM.png)
OS: Manjaro Linux x86_64

Comment: I think just reloading (opening and closing) the file again or restarting vs-code should fix that issue. If the 2 color boxes are what your concerned about that is.

Comment: (fixed) I don't know if this is related, but when I disable Vue Language Features (Volar) extensions the color picker came back to only showing once.

Comment: That's not a thing that will give you problems for anything, that happens when you put the same value twice and then delete one, just close and open you vs code, or restart your pc if you don't like it, if you're having any other weird bugs while this is happening, jus restart your pc cause it mught be a compilation problem.